# How to make strings into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I try to edit one of the column data into the format I want by using `csv.DictReader()`, the code is like this:

```
import csv
import time
with open('201701.csv') as inf:
        reader = csv.DictReader(inf)
        for row in reader:
            date = row['日期']
            d = date.split('/')
            year = int(d[0]) + 1911
            month = str(d[1])
            day = str(d[2])
            date_ = str(year) + "{0:2}".format(month) + "{0:2}".format(day)
            print(date_)
```

the outcome is like this:

```
20170103
20170104
20170105
20170106
20170109
20170110
20170111
20170112
20170113
20170116
20170117
20170118
20170119
20170120
20170123
20170124
```

But I want the data in the way like this:

```
date_list = ['20170103', '20170104', '20170105', '20170106', '20170109', '20170110', '20170111', '20170112', '20170113', '20170116', '20170117', '20170118', '20170119', '20170120', '20170123', '20170124']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it as a generator. This gives you the ability to iterate over the sequence of dates from the file, or collect them together in a list. I have simplified your code :

```
import csv
import time

def get_dates(inf):
    for row in csv.DictReader(inf):
        year, month, day = row['日期'].split('/')
        yield '{}{:02}{:02}'.format(int(year) + 1911, int(month), int(day))
```

Usage:

```
# Collect into a list
with open('201701.csv') as inf:
    date_list = list(get_dates(inf))
    print(date_list)

# Or iterate over the dates
with open('201701.csv') as inf:
    for date in get_dates(inf):
        print(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output is like that because you print a single string date using `print(date_)` iteratively. That is not a list at all.

To make a list, append your date string to a list `date_list`:

```
import csv
import time
date_list = []    # create list of date
with open('201701.csv') as inf:with open('201701.csv') as inf:
        reader = csv.DictReader(inf)
        for row in reader:
            date = row['日期']
            d = date.split('/')
            year = int(d[0]) + 1911
            month = str(d[1])
            day = str(d[2])
            date_ = str(year) + "{0:2}".format(month) + "{0:2}".format(day)
            date_list.append(date_)  # append your date string to list
print(date_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a `date_list` then you should make one!

```
import csv
import time
date_list = []
with open('201701.csv') as inf:with open('201701.csv') as inf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inf)
    for row in reader:
        date = row['日期']
        d = date.split('/')
        year = int(d[0]) + 1911
        month = str(d[1])
        day = str(d[2])
        date_ = str(year) + "{0:2}".format(month) + "{0:2}".format(day)
        print(date_)
        date_list.append(date_)
print(date_list)
```